# How to link to a CSS Stylesheet uploaded on a FTP server

Tags: html, css, ftp

I have my CSS stylesheets (one for display and one for print) uploaded onto a FTP server. When I try and link them to my page on my website (which is a Tumblr blog) the CSS isn't implemented. I'm not sure why...... Help?

The links I have look like this:

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ftp://servername.ca/MyName/aboutpagenavigationscreenstyles.css">
  < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ftp://servername.ca/MyName/aboutpagenavigationprintstyles.css" media="print">
```

Obviously, I've replaced the actual server's name with 'servername' and my name (which is the name of the folder the sheets are in) with 'MyName'. Also, there's no space between < and link, that was just so it would show.

When I go to that link, it requires my login.

Also, since this web page is on Tumblr, through their editing software it shows the text as different colours, and right now it's all green, which means it's correct. But it doesn't work...

Comment: Your link to stylesheet in index.html should be relative to index.html

Comment: Why are you hosting CSS on an FTP server instead of an HTTP server?

Comment: You are trying to get a file via FTP on an HTTP. FTP and HTTP use different ports and works on different rules. So you cannot reach resources via FTP using an HTTP

Comment: I'm using an FTP server because my teacher supplied one; this is for an assignment for a class.

Comment: @er-han you CAN link things to a page on a FTP server, I know it's possible, but maybe just not CSS? I'm just not sure......
Basically, my CSS sheet is uploaded on a FTP server, and I want it to apply to my Tumblr page. But it's not implementing.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

If you do not have the ability to access your CSS file via HTTP, then I would suggest you do the following. I **do not** suggest you put your username and password for anything in a plaintext file such as HTML.

Add this to your page preferably in the `<head>` section, although if that is not an option, you can put it in the `<body>`.

Example:

```
<body>
     <style type="text/css" media="screen">
          Your CSS
     </style>
     <style type="text/css" media="print">
          Your CSS
     </style>
     <p>Your HTML</p>
```

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp for more information.

---

Can you view/download the file using (http://servername.ca/MyName/aboutpagenavigationscreenstyles.css) replacing servername with your domain?

If so, use the link below.

```
<link href="http://servername.ca/MyName/aboutpagenavigationscreenstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="http://servername.ca/MyName/aboutpagenavigationscreenstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

This should be what you need. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: This does not answer the question which specifically asks about CSS at the FTP server. You just show how to embed CSS located at the HTTP server instead.

Comment: Sure this is a correct answer, beacuse you can't link a resource to an FTP link...

Comment: Thank you, I'm confused as to the downvotes...I didn't want to respond with a negative response. :)

Comment: @TAG: the OP has already included an example in his question, i.e. URL syntax of `ftp://`. Only this does not work but it will not help if you replace the ftp protocol simply with http. This might work if the both protocols at the server are mapped at exactly the same path but this is usually not the case.

Comment: @GiacomoPaita: just because the ftp:// link does not work because *"...you can't link a resource to an FTP link.."* does not mean that http:// will magically work with the same path - usually not.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't just replace the protocol, I used the proper syntax for including a CSS file in a page.

While the OP does not mention how his hosting provider handles FTP/HTTP interconnectedness, most that I use utilize FTP to upload the files and then HTTP to view from the file structure. So that when you upload a file via FTP (ftp://yoursite.com), you should be able to view it with HTTP (http://yousite.com).

Comment: I've tried replacing ftp:// with http instead and no, it didn't work.

Also to answer your question in your answer @TAG no I can't see or download my css from the link with http in front (i get a 404 error page). I CAN, however, see it with ftp in front, BUT I have to put my login first.

I've seen some pages online saying you have to put username:password@servername instead, but I've tried that too, and still nothing :((

Comment: I've just done a test, and if I take my whole coding for the whole page (with the links like that), put it on a notepad doc ending in .html (obviously), and uploaded it to the FTP file, everything works great. So that's a thing. Still doesn't solve my problem, though.....

Comment: @AllyB Well...I'm not sure how to link a CSS file via FTP and I highly don't suggest using your username and password in a plaintext file such as HTML. What I would suggest is adding the style tags and putting your CSS within those. I have edited my answer to show what I am talking about.